# What momentary switch should I use?

Tags: pcb, switches, button, toggle-switch

I want a switch that has 2 distinct non-momentary states (say `UP` and `Down`) and a momentary state. In both states (`UP` and `Down`), the switch should be able to go to Its momentary state.
Exactly just like a turn signal handle switch in a car: up, down and in both states we can have high beam.

What type of switch should I use?

Comment: Simplest solution is, as you wrote, to get a turn and light switch in a car parts shop. There is low probability, i think, to get general purpose switch of such type due to low demand. You may consider to replace it with separate switch + button, to make it yourself or adopt any car switch, depends of your demand. Could you specify your target?

Comment: This switch is going to be as a part of a product in automotive after-market industry. I want to make sure that an after-market products company can make the product with a such switch.

Comment: Why not to buy such switches from manufacturers? They are all different, each for each vehicle series.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an automotive 'on-off-on' momentary SPDT toggle switch. Please ensure that the current rating of the switch is adequate for your requirement.